# Connect to Homestead Redis instance from local machine

Tags: redis, connection, homestead

I'm trying to use [redisinsight](https://redislabs.com/blog/redisinsight-gui) to connect to the Homestead redis instance, but when I insert the default connection parameters, I get the following error:

```
Could not connect: Error 61 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. Connection refused.
```

Same error with `localhost` as host.

[image]

I made sure redis is running:
[image]

Any idea why and how to connect?

I run Homestead v7.2.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Connect to your vagrant box
- Navigate to `/etc/redis/` directory and open `redis.conf`
- find `bind 127.0.0.1` line and replace with `bind 0.0.0.0`
- restart the server by `service redis-server restart` command
- Navigate to redisinsight
- Type `192.168.10.10`(the ip address written in your homestead.yaml) in Host & `6379` in Port

Comment: thanks @Ersoy, but for some reason my `/etc/redis/redis.conf`, inside homestead, is empty... o_O

Comment: what does `service redis-server status` print ?  any rows such as `ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)` @Stefano

Comment: `redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-06-09 17:17:56 UTC; 6h ago
     Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
           man:redis-server(1)
  Process: 1097 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1297 (redis-server)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 2319)
   CGroup: /system.slice/redis-server.service
           └─1297 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379`

Comment: @Stefano almost same - it should print the all config `sudo su` and `cat /etc/redis/redis.conf`

Comment: `redis-cli config get bind` should print the `127.0.0.1` @Stefano

Comment: this is the output: `1) "bind"
2) "127.0.0.1 ::1"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215623/discussion-between-ersoy-and-stefano).